# Create a binary completeness map

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm touching the goal of my project, but I'm getting a problem on : How I can create a completeness map ?
I have lots of data, a field with maybe 500.000 objects which are represented by dots in my plot with different zoom :

[image: Without zoom]
[image: First zoom]
[image: Second zoom]

I would like to create a mask, I mean, cut my plot in tiny pixels, and say if I have an object in this pixel, I get the value : 1 (black for example) elif, I have not object in my pixel, I get the value : 0 (white for example).

I'll create a mask and I could divide each field by this mask.
The problem is that I don't know how I can process in order to make that :/

I create a first script in order to get a selection on my data. This one :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

                ###################################
                # Fichier contenant le champ brut #
                ###################################

filename = '/home/valentin/Desktop/Field52_combined_final_roughcal.fits'

# Ouverture du fichier à l'aide d'astropy  
field = fits.open(filename)   
print "Ouverture du fichier : " + str(filename)       

# Lecture des données fits
tbdata = field[1].data   
print "Lecture des données du fits"            

                ###############################
                # Application du tri sur PROB #
                ###############################

mask = np.bitwise_and(tbdata['PROB'] < 1.1, tbdata['PROB'] > -0.1)  
new_tbdata = tbdata[mask]   
print "Création du Masque"       

            #################################################
            # Détermination des valeurs extremales du champ #
            #################################################

# Détermination de RA_max et RA_min 
RA_max = np.max(new_tbdata['RA'])
RA_min = np.min(new_tbdata['RA'])
print "RA_max vaut :     " + str(RA_max)
print "RA_min vaut :     " + str(RA_min)

# Détermination de DEC_max et DEC_min   
DEC_max = np.max(new_tbdata['DEC'])
DEC_min = np.min(new_tbdata['DEC'])
print "DEC_max vaut :   " + str(DEC_max)
print "DEC_min vaut :   " + str(DEC_min)

            #########################################
            # Calcul de la valeur centrale du champ #
            #########################################

# Détermination de RA_moyen et DEC_moyen
RA_central = (RA_max + RA_min)/2.
DEC_central = (DEC_max + DEC_min)/2.

print "RA_central vaut : " + str(RA_central)
print "DEC_central vaut : " + str(DEC_central)

print " "
print " ------------------------------- "
print " "

        ##############################
        # Détermination de X et de Y #
        ##############################


# Creation du tableau
new_col_data_X = array = (new_tbdata['RA'] - RA_central) * np.cos(DEC_central)
new_col_data_Y = array = new_tbdata['DEC'] - DEC_central
print 'Création du tableau'


# Creation des nouvelles colonnes
col_X = fits.Column(name='X', format='D', array=new_col_data_X)
col_Y = fits.Column(name='Y', format='D', array=new_col_data_Y)
print 'Création des nouvelles colonnes X et Y'


# Creation de la nouvelle table
tbdata_final = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(new_tbdata.columns + col_X + col_Y)

# Ecriture du fichier de sortie .fits
tbdata_final.writeto('{}_{}'.format(filename,'mask'))
print 'Ecriture du nouveau fichier mask'

field.close()
```

Ok, it's working ! But now, the second part is this to the moment :

```
###################################################
###################################################
###################################################

filename = '/home/valentin/Desktop/Field52_combined_final_roughcal.fits_mask'

print 'Fichier en cours de traitement' + str(filename) + '\n'

# Ouverture du fichier à l'aide d'astropy
field = fits.open(filename)         

# Lecture des données fits  
tbdata = field[1].data    

figure = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot (tbdata['X'], tbdata['Y'], '.')
plt.show()
```

Do you have any idea how process ?
How I can cut my plot in tiny bin ?

Thank you !
UPDATE :

After the answer from armatita, I updated my script :

```
###################################################
###################################################
###################################################

filename = '/home/valentin/Desktop/Field52_combined_final_roughcal.fits_mask'

print 'Fichier en cours de traitement' + str(filename) + '\n'

# Opening file with astropy
field = fits.open(filename)         

# fits data reading 
tbdata = field[1].data    

##### BUILDING A GRID FOR THE DATA ########
nodesx,nodesy = 360,360   # PIXELS IN X, PIXELS IN Y
firstx,firsty = np.min(tbdata['X']),np.min(tbdata['Y'])
sizex = (np.max(tbdata['X'])-np.min(tbdata['X']))/nodesx
sizey = (np.max(tbdata['Y'])-np.min(tbdata['Y']))/nodesy
grid = np.zeros((nodesx+1,nodesy+1),dtype='bool') # PLUS 1 TO ENSURE ALL DATA IS INSIDE GRID

# CALCULATING GRID COORDINATES OF DATA
indx = np.int_((tbdata['X']-firstx)/sizex)
indy = np.int_((tbdata['Y']-firsty)/sizey)
grid[indx,indy] = True  # WHERE DATA EXISTS SET TRUE

# PLOT MY FINAL IMAGE
plt.imshow(grid.T,origin='lower',cmap='binary',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

I find this plot :

[image: solution]

So, when I play with the bin size, I can see more or less blank which indicate object or not in my pixel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a process of inserting your data into a grid (pixel wise, or node wise). The following example builds a grid (2D array) and calculates the "grid coordinates" for the sample data. Once it has those grid coordinates (which in true are nothing but array indexes) you can just set those elements to True. Check the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
y = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)

##### BUILDING A GRID FOR THE DATA ########
nodesx,nodesy = 100,100   # PIXELS IN X, PIXELS IN Y
firstx,firsty = x.min(),y.min()
sizex = (x.max()-x.min())/nodesx
sizey = (y.max()-y.min())/nodesy
grid = np.zeros((nodesx+1,nodesy+1),dtype='bool') # PLUS 1 TO ENSURE ALL DATA IS INSIDE GRID

# CALCULATING GRID COORDINATES OF DATA
indx = np.int_((x-firstx)/sizex)
indy = np.int_((y-firsty)/sizey)
grid[indx,indy] = True  # WHERE DATA EXISTS SET TRUE

# PLOT MY FINAL IMAGE
plt.imshow(grid.T,origin='lower',cmap='binary',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: small pixels in imshow]

Notice I'm showing an image with imshow. Should I decrease the number of pixels (20,20 = nodesx, nodesy) I get:

[image: big pixels in imshow]

Also for a more automatic plot in matplotlib you can consider [hexbin](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin).

Comment: Thank you to your answer ! I will try few later :)